# How can I set up log4j to send email using NTLM authentication?

Tags: java, log4j

Is there any way to send an email using Java log4j via an exchange server that only allows NTLM-based authentication?

Comment: log4j logs. Other APIs send mail thru mail servers (queue the messages). What do you want to do?

Comment: log4j has an SMTP appender, however it only supports smtp auth login authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default appender relies just on SMTP auth, so it won't make it by itself. You could create a custom email appender as stated [here](http://horrikhalid.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/how-to-use-log4j-with-gmail/) (linked just to state who shared the idea first, it's not mine). It basically creates the appender where Authentication is done

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;

import org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender;

/**
* @author DEV
*
*/
public class GmailAppender extends SMTPAppender {
private boolean startTLS = false;

@Override
protected Session createSession() {
Properties props = null;
try {
props = new Properties(System.getProperties());
} catch (SecurityException ex) {
props = new Properties();
}
String prefix = "mail.smtp";
if (this.getSMTPProtocol() != null) {
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", this.getSMTPProtocol());
prefix = "mail." + this.getSMTPProtocol();
}

if (this.getSMTPHost() != null)
props.put(prefix + ".host", this.getSMTPHost());
if (this.getSMTPPort() > 0)
props.put(prefix + ".port", String.valueOf(this.getSMTPPort()));
if (this.startTLS)
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Authenticator auth = null;
if (this.getSMTPPassword() != null && this.getSMTPUsername() != null) {
props.put(prefix + ".auth", "true");
auth = new Authenticator() {
...
```

And then, in the config file,

```
#email appender
log4j.appender.mail=com.horri.GmailAppender
#defines how othen emails are send
log4j.appender.mail.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.mail.From=yourmail@servermail.com
log4j.appender.mail.To=yourmail@gmail.com
log4j.appender.mail.startTLS = true
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPUsername=yourgmailusername
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPPassword=yourgmailpasswd
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=Log ...
log4j.appender.mail.threshold=error
log4j.appender.mail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**EDIT: Sometimes helpful gets mixed with "laziness-supportive". Hence, here's a apache-licensed implementation of NTLM auth. http://code.google.com/p/ntlm-java/ Hope it works fine.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't NTLM authentication.

Comment: I know it is not. If you read carefully, the idea is NOT to copy/paste BUT to create the appender by yourself and authenticate using other library that handles NTLM. log4j won't do it by itself.

Comment: An answer as vague as "you could code it yourself using a third party library" (w/o even mentioning any particular library) is about as least helpful an answer as anyone could give.

Comment: Edited. Hope it helps some more.